# whats this korean sentence mean? 배우 태연의 공중파 데뷔작은? Do they want a year and what they want?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

What is the meaning of this Korean sentence?

배우 태연의 공중파 데뷔작은?
Do they want a year and what they want ?

Answer (score 1):

"What is the public network debut production of actor/actress Taeyeon?"

공중파 means public network, mostly TV, as opposed to cable network. It is a compound of 공중(公衆; "public") and 파(波; suffix "wave")

데뷔작 is a compound of the word 데뷔(obviously from French début) and 작(作; suffix "piece of work, production")